# modal form disappears without on clicking the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

We have a form that works correctly and submits via correctly.  The problem arises when I turned the form into a modal(bootstrap).  When the form renders a user can tab through and type just fine.  The select boxes work and one can press enter on the keyboard; however, when I use the mouse and click on any element on the modal including background it disappears.  Please help.  Here is the code:

```
    $('#new_event').click( function() {
      $('#all-events').toggle(false);
      $('#all-invitations').toggle(false);
      $('#friend-requests').toggle(false);
      $('#feed').toggle(false);
      $('#time-select-start').toggle(false);
      $('#time-select-end').toggle(false);
      $('#event-type-select').toggle(false);
      $('#event_location').val('Current Location');
      $('#event_location').attr('readonly',true);
      $('#new-event').toggle();
      check_dashboard();
    });
```

The view:

```
%a{'href' => '#new-event','data-toggle' => 'modal', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-small'}
      new event
:
:
#new-event{'class' => 'modal hide fade'}
      = render 'events/new_event'
```

Here is the form:

```
.modal-form
.fieldset
    .container
        %center
            .well.span6{:style => "position:relative; right:2.1%;background-color:#ffffff;"}

                %h1{:style => 'font-family:eight_one;font-weight:normal;color:#ff6699;'} quick rondé 
                = form_for(@event, html: { class: 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
                    %div
                        = f.text_field :name,:autofocus => 'true',:placeholder => "event name"
                    %div
                        = f.text_area :description, rows: 3, :placeholder => "give your friends some more details and convince them to come "
                    %div
                        = f.text_field :location,:placeholder => "location"
                    %div
                        = f.text_field :event_type, :placeholder => 'event type'
                    %ul.span3.dropdown-menu#event-select-type{:style => 'position:absolute; left:27.65%;top:63%;',"role" => "menu"}
                        %li
                            %a#Food{:href => '#'} food
                            %a#Drink{:href => '#'} drink
                            %a#Other{:href => '#'} other

                    %div
                        = f.text_field :start, :placeholder => 'start time'
                    %ul.span3.dropdown-menu#time-select-start{:style => 'position:absolute; left:27.65%;top:73%;',"role" => "menu"}
                        %li#time-list-start
                    %div
                        = f.text_field :end, :placeholder => 'end time'
                    %ul.span3.dropdown-menu#time-select-end{:style => 'position:absolute; left:27.65%;top:82%;',"role" => "menu"}
                        %li#time-list-end
                    %a{'data-dismiss' => 'modal'} Cancel        
                    = f.submit value: 'Create', class: 'btn btn-info'
```

Any help would be great.  I am new to javascript, haml, and modals...Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the elements on the page with Firebug for example? probably there's some div with higher z-index than the form, try to find it if exist and set it's z-index to be lower than the modal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to prevent default actions on form?

```
    $(document).bind("modal-form",function(e){
     return false;
    });
```

or to handle mouse events?

```
    $(".modal-form").mouseup(function(e){
      switch(e.which){
        case 1:
          left click event;
        break;
        case 2:
          middle click event;
        break;
        case 3:
          right click event;
        break;
        default:
          default action;
       }
      });
```